# Silverstripe datepicker in frontend form only working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, datepicker, frontend, silverstripe

I am using the datepicker that comes with Silverstripe in an front-end form. I am also using the BootsForm Module. This is the code that works in Chrome:

```
      $fields->dataFieldByName('Birthday')
          ->setAttribute('type', 'date')
          ->setAttribute('data-datepicker', true)
          ->setAttribute('data-date-format', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

The birthdayfield is a datefield. The datepicker is not showing in Firefox or Safari. I don't know why. I get no errors in the browser console. I am sure, i am not the first person with this problem. So maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a SilverStripe issue. You're just creating a HTML5 date-field and set the datepicker attributes. Most browsers don't support native date-pickers (yet), see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

You could add some JS that progressively enhances your date-field with a date-picker though. Here's a [tutorial](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/30/creating-a-native-html5-datepicker-with-a-fallback-to-jquery-ui/) that uses jQuery UI. If you're not using jQuery/jQueryUI, [Pickaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) is a good alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much that help a lot. I didn´t know this is a HTML5 feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can have it show the datepicker by adding `->setConfig('showcalendar', true)`